# [HLS Streaming - SWIFT Player]HALPlugIn-DeviceGetCurrentTime Issue

Tags: swift, http-live-streaming

I am currently working on developing an HLS player. While testing it on the simulator using Xcode, I noticed that it plays audio but doesn't display video.

Below is the snippet of code

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/features/stable/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8") else {
            return
        }
        // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        print("created player")
        
        // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        
        // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            print("user started video")
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Error Trace

`HALPlugIn.cpp:551    HALPlugIn::DeviceGetCurrentTime: got an error from the plug-in routine, Error: 1937010544 (stop)`

I want smooth playback experience.

Comment: Have you look at Apple’s sample HLS player? It has all the functionality it is in the Apple docs

Answer (score 1):

After updating the xcode version the issue got resolved.